# In seed application can a application service be packaged in web module?

Tags: packaging, seedstack

For our web application we have written most of our code inside Resources classes. Now we want to unit test the web module with junit tests with "Simple Integration tests".

But we can only test our repositories and not the finders and other business logic with this kind of packaging.

Do we need to move our code from Resource classes to application services which can be injected in unit tests? If yes, can we write these services in web module? Normally we write these services in app module but in that case services don't have access to finders present in web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resources classes should only contain the code necessary to expose a REST API of your application: no business logic, no application (use-case) logic, no data access. The resource class should only **use** other components such as repositories, services and finders to achieve the desired result.

In SeedStack projects, especially if you're using the business framework, it is recommended that you respects the DDD layer model:

- The domain layer is where the business is expressed, by aggregates containing domain objects (entities and value objects) and by domain services.
- The application layer is responsible for driving the workflow of the application, executing the use cases of the system through application services. This layer can also be tested by unit tests and by simple integration tests.
- The interface layer handles the interaction with other systems. In your case, this is done with REST resources. These resources can rely on finders when necessary to query the database.

You can test any of these components with unit tests and [simple integration tests](http://seedstack.org/docs/seed/manual/testing/#simple-integration-tests) except for the REST resources since they depend upon a Web runtime environment. These can only be tested in [Web integration tests](http://seedstack.org/docs/seed/manual/testing/#web-integration-tests) (with Arquillian).

You can find an example of a finder tested by simple integration tests [here](https://github.com/seedstack/hub/blob/master/backend/src/test/java/org/seedstack/it/mongo/UserMongoFinderIT.java) and [here](https://github.com/seedstack/hub/blob/master/backend/src/test/java/org/seedstack/it/mongo/ComponentMongoFinderIT.java).